# How to get information of users logging into linux running in a Docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker

I need to get a list of all users logging into a linux machine ( local logins or/and remote (ssh) logins ) running on a Docker container. i want to get this list in my python app running in the container.
How can i do this?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please provide an example of things you have tried so far so that we can help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Generally you don't: Docker containers are at least somewhat isolated from their host system, and if you need to administer the host in some way, you need to run the tool from outside a container in the host environment.

Answer (score 0):

To briefly point out the steps:

- Configure login monitoring on the linux machine (Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143898/277952) how it could be done).
- Mount /var/log as a volume into your docker-container. Be careful though: If you have SELinux configured on your host you might run into the [following problem](https://serverfault.com/q/771117/348556) at some point.
- Read and parse the log-file in your python app.